# Problema al hacer git pull desde proyecto laravel montado en ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, git, ubuntu, git-pull

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación web en laravel y le agregue un botón que ejecuta un `git pull origin main` en php usando el método `exec()`, el problema esta en que siempre me arroja este error **fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'www-data@avtserver.(none)')**
ya le agregue las configuraciones globales de git para email y user:

`git config --global user.name "mi nombre"`

`git config --global user.email "mi email"`

también configure una clave ssh para que no me pida autenticación, ya verifique que mi usuario www-data tenga permisos en los directorios de mi proyecto laravel, pero nada funciona, cuando trato de ejecutar `git pull origin main` desde mi terminal de mi maquina virtual ubuntu lo hace sin problemas, el detalle surge cuando se ejecuta desde mi aplicación laravel.

este es el comando que ejecuta mi php en laravel:
`$actualizar_sistema = exec('git pull origin main --no-edit 2>&1');`
ya la salida:
**fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'www-data@avtserver.(none)')**

Comment: Podrias mostrar el comando y la salida en la pregunta?

Comment: ¿No sería en --system en vez de en --global donde quieres setear esa configuración? Porque segun entiendo --global va a ser para tu usuario, pero el comando lo está ejecutando otro usuario https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#SCOPES

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo eso resolvió el problema no sabia que había un parámetro --system

Comment: Vale, si así lo resolviste por favor agrega una respuesta explicando cómo lo hiciste. También ten en cuenta que par hacerlo así vas a necesitar permisos de administrador, que no siempre es posible en un servidor en producción

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar el problema solo fue cuestión de ejecutar nuevamente los comandos esta vez usando --system en vez de --global:

"git config --system user.name "mi nombre"

"git config --system user.email "mi email"

para dar de alta las configuraciones a nivel sistema y pueda ser reconocido por el usuario www-data cuando ejecute git pull